# How to generate a unique key for an array?

Tags: php, hash-collision

I'd like to generate a unique identifier based on the content of an array.  My initial approach was to simply do:

```
$key = md5(json_encode($array));
```

However, I'd like to be absolutely sure that the key is unique and there is a remote possibility that two distinct arrays can produce the same md5 hash.  Current idea is to do:

```
$key = base64_encode(json_encode($array));
```

This is guaranteed to be unique but produces quite a long key.  Can I use sha512 or does this type of hash also have the same potential for key collision as md5?  Is there any way to generate a shorter key than the base64 method which is 100% guaranteed to be unique?

To be 100% clear, my question is: **How can I generate the shortest possible 100% unique identifier for a set of data?**

Comment: should it be based on the content of the array? if not, use uuid or something similar ?

Comment: Yes the array contents - updated question.  Not sure I understand your suggestion.  The arrays do not contain any unique id.  That's exactly what I'd like to generate.

Comment: base64 isn't a hash, it is the data itself, and reversible, the collision chance will be based on the hash function that you use, I don't think any have a complete 100% chance, but they should be very close to it.

Comment: Your question is about generating a 100% guaranteed unique key, but you are using the contents of the array to generate a hash. Should the unique key be derived from the contents of the array or not? That was my question.

Comment: @AdamForbis - that's fine.  It just needs to be unique.

Comment: Please give some more information about your use case. If you want to use it as an identifier, why not use an integer (like auto_increment) in MySQL)? If you want just a hash, why is it that important to have a unique hash?

Comment: @Robert - yes I answered your question.  Again, the answer is yes.

Comment: @StephanVierkant - I don't want it to be an integer because in the scenario that I encounter the same array I need to key to be the same - which is why hashing makes sense.  It's important because the data will be stored and a collision would result in overwriting unique data.

Comment: If you use a hashing function, which has limited amount of possible values, then by definition you **can NEVER be 100% sure**.  It's improbable, that during your lifetime, you'll ever get a collision even for `MD5`, but - that's not 100% sure. This is an XY problem, why don't you ask about the real problem you're having? Obviously, you're working with data and you need to ensure you're not receiving duplicates or something similar. I'd leave this perceived solution aside and ask about the real issue which this hashing approach was supposed to solve.

Comment: @Mjh - Thanks.  I am trying to keep my question general enough to be useful to the community. I believe the question as it is, does address the "real issue" - which how to generate the shortest possible 100% unique identifier for a set of data.

Comment: @billynoah - but it's not useful for community. Your problem isn't even defined. You want to uniquely identify *<something>* - give it a number. There are infinite numbers. Increase number by 1 every time. That's it, that's **shortest**, **fastest** and **safest** method. There's nothing in this universe that can defeat this method that I described, popularly known as `auto_increment` in MySQL. If you want same input to contain same number, then you hash it. I still believe this is an XY problem but  you obviously solved your real issue by hashing stuff.

Comment: @Mjh - that's not correct.  Because if I am iterating through a series of arrays and I encounter a set of duplicate values I need it to reference the same key - which autoincrementing will not do.  That's why my question asks about generating a key based on the data set, not based on uniqueness only.

Comment: @billynoah I did touch upon the subject with unique identifier and unique identifier for the same data. It's good that you got told, and accepted, the answer about hashing. However, what I was responding to was your comment about usefulness for community - this question isn't really useful, and I still believe you'd get way further with your issue had you asked about it directly. Let's not beat the dead cat, have a nice day :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want a 100% guaranteed unique key to match your content, then the only way is to use the full length of your content. You can use the json_encoded string as-is, or you could run it through base64_encode() or bin2hex() or similar if you want a string that doesn't have any "special" characters. Any hash function like md5, sha1, sha256 etc obviously cannot be 100% unique - because they have a fixed length, and due to the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle there must necessarily be non-unique results for input content that is larger than the hash.

In practice, md5 and sha1 collisions have now been published, but stronger hash functions exist where no collisions are known or expected for a long time, so you could also look into using a modern hash algorithm and be fairly safe that you will not have any duplicates.

Comment: Thanks.  I believe this answers my question.